# CYGWIN sshd "port 22: Connection refused"

Tags: cygwin, ssh

Googled this to death, cannot resolve. I cannot connect to my CYGWIN sshd from another machine. Netstat shows connection is established. Can connect locally, no problem.

```
[oracle@aserver ~]$  ssh myid@mycomp
ssh: connect to host mycomp port 22: Connection refused
```

On mycomp:

```
$ netstat -a | grep ssh
  TCP    MYCOMP:ssh            MYCOMP.mydomain.com:0  LISTENING
  TCP    MYCOMP:1161           aserver.mydomain.com:ssh  ESTABLISHED
```

Successful login from the localhost:

```
$ ssh myid@mycomp
myid@mycomp's password:
Last login: Tue Sep 14 14:27:30 2010 from mycomp.mydomain.com
Fanfare!!!
You are successfully logged in to this server!!!
```

I'm on XP sp3, updated CYGWIN today. Tried cleanup and reconfigure, didn't help.

Cleanup (credit to Herb Maeder http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-10/msg00370.html) :

```
# Remove sshd service
cygrunsrv --stop sshd
cygrunsrv --remove sshd
# Delete any sshd or related users (such as cyg_server) from /etc/passwd
#   (use your favorite editor)
# Delete any sshd or relaged users (such as cyg_server) from the system
net user sshd /delete
```

Configure:

```
$ ssh-host-config -y
*** Query: Overwrite existing /etc/ssh_config file? (yes/no) yes
*** Info: Creating default /etc/ssh_config file
*** Query: Overwrite existing /etc/sshd_config file? (yes/no) yes
*** Info: Creating default /etc/sshd_config file
*** Info: Privilege separation is set to yes by default since OpenSSH 3.3.
*** Info: However, this requires a non-privileged account called 'sshd'.
*** Info: For more info on privilege separation read /usr/share/doc/openssh/README.privsep.
*** Query: Should privilege separation be used? (yes/no) yes
*** Info: Note that creating a new user requires that the current account have
*** Info: Administrator privileges.  Should this script attempt to create a
*** Query: new local account 'sshd'? (yes/no) yes
*** Info: Updating /etc/sshd_config file
*** Query: Overwrite existing /etc/inetd.d/sshd-inetd file? (yes/no) yes
*** Info: Creating default /etc/inetd.d/sshd-inetd file
*** Info: Updated /etc/inetd.d/sshd-inetd


*** Warning: The following functions require administrator privileges!

*** Query: Do you want to install sshd as a service?
*** Query: (Say "no" if it is already installed as a service) (yes/no) yes
*** Query: Enter the value of CYGWIN for the daemon: []

*** Info: The sshd service has been installed under the LocalSystem
*** Info: account (also known as SYSTEM). To start the service now, call
*** Info: `net start sshd' or `cygrunsrv -S sshd'.  Otherwise, it
*** Info: will start automatically after the next reboot.

*** Info: Host configuration finished. Have fun!

myid@MYCOMP /cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/myid
$ cygrunsrv -S sshd

myid@MYCOMP /cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/myid
$ cygrunsrv -Q sshd
Service             : sshd
Display name        : CYGWIN sshd
Current State       : Running
Controls Accepted   : Stop
Command             : /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you telnet to port 22 from another computer?

```
telnet <mycomp> 22
```

If you're getting a connection refused (and you can connect via localhost), this is definitely a firewall issue.  There are other firewalls besides Windows Firewall--McAfee, ZoneAlarm, etc., and it sounds like you're being blocked--since you can access it internally (indicating its listening on the correct port) but you can't access it externally (indicating external ports are closed).

Surprisingly, [Mozilla has a great look on configuring firewalls](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firewalls)--including the Windows Firewall.  Give it a try.  Just because you think there's no firewall running--doesn't mean there isn't.

Comment: It was our corporate firewall. What made me think it was not blocking is the second line of the netstat output (see second block of code from top) - the connection from the server to my machine. Then I realized this connection appears when I ssh to the server. Yes, I ssh to the server then ssh (scp actually) back to my machine.

Comment: Plus, it used to work before. something must've changed with the firewall upgrade we had recently.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance a Windows firewall is running?

Have you run your SSH client in either verbose or debug mode?

Comment: Windows firewall off.

Comment: [oracle@aserver ~]$   ssh -v -v -v myid@mycomp
    OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: Applying options for *
    debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to mycomp [111.11.11.11] port 22.
    debug1: connect to address 111.11.11.11 port 22: Connection refused
    ssh: connect to host mycomp port 22: Connection refused

Comment: that came out mashed together but you get the idea - there is no additional insight to be gained from the verbose output.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm gonna reinstall CYGWIN myself and delve deeper.

Comment: Ok. Installed the latest and greatest 1.7 release Cygwin on an XP SP2 box. After setting up SSHD with ssh-host-config, I tried to connect from my Win 7 desktop through PuTTY. Connection timed out (not refused though.) Went to the XP box and turned off firewall. Immediately after, I was able to SSH in with PuTTY. I wonder if SP3 is putting a twist on your situation?

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with this exact issue for a few weeks now. It may not apply directly to this case. But I am going to share my experience here, in the hope that it may help somebody.

The Cygwin SSHD is running on my Windows 7 Home Premium Box.

- I WAS able to ssh into the machine from localhost, or by typing out my IP address. This was attempted, and was successful in Putty.
- I was NOT able to ssh into the machine from any other device on the LAN.

  - I verified that this was not a firewall, or antivirus, or security issue. I tested this using apache portable on port 22. I was able to reach it on port 22. I also ensured that sshd.exe was given full ability to communicate on the network.
  - I turned off all firewall features on the machine. It was only windows defender, and windows firewall. This did not fix the problem
- after some digging around. I was able to find that it was something with putty itself. For some reason, I am able to use an openssh client from my linux server (out in the cloud) in, without any problem. I think it has something to do with putty keys.
- I ran putty.exe -cleanup and still had the problem.
- On one of my linux servers, I get this ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
- On another one of my linux servers, it just connects.

Hope this helps.

Devon

--EDIT--
Okay. It started to get even stranger. I have 4 cloud servers, each tied to a different domain. One server could login to my sshd while others couldn't.

I fixed this by commenting out all of the entries in hosts.deny.
I also adjusted my hosts.allow file to look like this.

```
ALL : localhost 127.0.0.1/32 [::1]/128 [::ffff:127.0.0.1]/128 : allow
SSHD : ALL
```

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same error and found out that my sshd was not running. So start your sshd using `net start sshd` and it might work for you.

Comment: OP shows that he can log in locally, so this isn't his problem.